# UTF-8 encoding yields weird characters in Android

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8

I have an Android app where I need to output some characters shich are not ASCII. My Java file where I set those characters is encoded as UTF-8:

```
 public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                                              long id, boolean checked) {
            mode.setSubtitle(llista.getCheckedItemCount() + " elements sel·leccionats.");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.setTitle("Sel·lecciona!");
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            if (inflater != null) {
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.menudetallllista, menu);
            }
            return true;
        }
```

But the output I get is this:

[image: Capture]

Is there any way to fix this besides changing the file Encoding to Windows-1252?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One work around is to unicode escape the chars in the Java source:

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("Some chars: \u00BF \u00EC \u00E1 \u00E9 \u00ED \u00F3 \u00FA \u00FC \u00F1");
```

or the strings XML file:

```
<string name="test">Again:  \u00BF \u00EC \u00E1 \u00E9 \u00ED \u00F3 \u00FA \u00FC \u00F1</string>
```

[image]